# bash shell script, searching for complex line in makefile (shell parameter expansion issue)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an annoying problem, I want a script to search through a makefile (using grep) for a particular annoying line. The problem is best illustrated concretely:

someMakefile (minimal Makefile):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo bla bla
OBJ_DIR='something'
EXE_FILE='my_exe'
cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.
echo 'doing something else now'
```

testScript.sh (test for the existence of the difficult line):

cat testScript.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
foundNumLines = $(grep -in 'cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.' someMakefile)
echo "foundNumLines = $foundNumLines"
set +x
```

From the commandline (this DOES work):

```
$ grep -in 'cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.' someMakefile
5:cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.
```

From the script (this does NOT work and I cannot figure out how to make it work):

```
$ ./testScript.sh 
++ grep -in 'cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.' someMakefile
+ foundNumLines = 5:cp '$(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE)' ../bin/.
./testScript.sh: line 4: foundNumLines: command not found
+ echo 'foundNumLines = '
foundNumLines = 
+ set +x
```

When "grep" works from the script, I wanted to use maybe "wc" or similar, to detect the presence of the line and then do something, based on this...

I just cannot make it work, tried many combinations of "'" \' etc - I hope you understand, what I'm trying to achieve, please help with ideas/suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign values to variables, you need `var=value` and not `var = value`. Spaces are significant in this context and that's why you get the `command not found` error from this line:

```
foundNumLines = $(grep -in 'cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.' someMakefile)
```

That isn't a variable assignment, it is three commands: `foundNumLines`, `=`, and `$(grep ... )`. What you need is:

```
foundNumLines=$(grep -in 'cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.' someMakefile)
```

---

I know you said it was a makefile, but I should point out that the `$()` construct has meaning in the shell as well. `$(foo)` will run the *command* `foo` and return its output. Therefore, this line:

```
cp $(OBJ_DIR)/$(EXE_FILE) ../bin/.
```

Will first try to execute `$OBJ_DIR` and `$EXE_FILE` as commands and insert their output in the place of the variables. Since `OBJ_DIR` will presumably not be a command, this means that you will be executing

```
cp / ../bin/.
```

Or, if `EXE_FILE` is in your path and executable:

```
cp /$outputOfExec_File ../bin/.
```

(by the way, there's no need for `.` there, `../bin/` is the same as `../bin/.`).

I thought I'd mention this since you have a bash shebang at the top of your makefile example, so I am assuming you are executing it as a shell script.

Comment: Oh, stupid me... So, basically I think the major issue was that I've been programmed in other languages lately and just entirely forget to remove the space around the equal-sign (var=value and not var = value). For the reference it's great that you added a detailed explanation (about the OBJ_DIR being empty here etc, I know - I just wanted to include a minimal example and therefore it's empty here), if other people see it, it might be helpful, so I've upvoted and marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @OkayDokey yeah, I know the feeling. It takes some getting used to. :)